# Non-degenerate limits of topoi

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be an elementary topos with natural numbers object $\mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathbb{C}$ be a cofiltered internal category in $\mathcal{E}$.  Suppose we have a diagram of shape $\mathbb{C}$ in $\mathfrak{LTop}/\mathcal{E}$ whose vertices are all non-degenerate, where $\mathfrak{LTop}$ is the 2-category of elementary topoi, localic geometric morphisms, and geometric transformations.  Is there a (nice) criterion for determining when the limit is non-degenerate?

If there's no general criterion, I'm still interested in the case where $\mathbb{C}$ is a downward directed poset, or even in the specific case where $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{N}^{op}$, the natural numbers with the opposite of the usual order, or the specific case where $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ considered as a discrete category (i.e. a "countable" product over $\mathcal{E}$).

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't this include as a special case the question of whether or not countable choice holds?

Comment: You may be right.  I'm fine with countable (or any) choice in the metatheory, but I would rather not assume it holds in the internal logic of $\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: There are several preservation properties proved in ["Continuous fibrations and inverse limits of toposes"](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1986__58_1/CM_1986__58_1_45_0/CM_1986__58_1_45_0.pdf) by Ieke Moerdijk, have you checked that?

Comment: I have.  Unfortunately in the situation I'm interested in I can't assume that the geometric morphisms in the diagram have any property besides being localic.

Comment: So what kind of conditions would you prefer? They should be either some sort of surjectivity or some sort of compactness...

Comment: Suppose I have a collection $\{\mathbb{T}_{n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ of geometric propositional theories in the same language, and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the universal model of $\mathbb{T}_{n+1}$ is a model of $\mathbb{T}_{n}$.  Is it necessary that all of the induced morphisms $f_{n}:\mathcal{E}[\mathbb{T}_{n+1}]\rightarrow \mathcal{E}[\mathbb{T}_{n}]$ be surjective for the inverse limit to be non-degenerate?  I was hoping some property (not implying surjectivity) of the sites would guarantee non-degneracy.